# Best type of abstraction for this job?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a class called Person with a property that specifies if there is a Grid object attached. There are 3 types of grid objects. 2 of them will have the exact same properties and the 3rd will have completely different ones.

What is the best type of abstraction to use so the Grid property in the Person class can accept all 3 types? By that I mean should I use an abstract class, base class, or interface? Or should I look into generics?

My thoughts are to use an abstract class, this way I can implement the properties and not have redundant code in the 2 classes that share the same properties. It will also force anyone adding new grid types to create a new class that is derived from it. I need this last part because I need to check which type of Grid object it is, using reflection, so I can add some conditional logic.

It just feels odd that the 3rd grid type will have these unnecessary properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the 3rd grid type has totally different properties then how can Person accept them all in the same way?  You can only 'abstract' commonalities.  You are passing 2 different things to Person - so I wouldn't try to abstract them just because they are both grids.

Comment: There can only be one of the grid types per person.

Comment: I see, well it's hard to understand the best way to implement that constraint without a broader understanding of the application.  On the surface however Person sounds like a business object, so giving it a direct reference to what is presumably a UI object could be said to be a code smell anyway.  But effectively you're using reflection to get around this design issue - you can almost certainly do better but how to do so requires more info.

Comment: Ok, I guess I used a really bad example. This is an asp.net mvc app and Person is actually a viewmodel for my person view. It contains the person's data and data associated for his grid of associated objects (orders).

Comment: In that example I'd start with Person holding the Orders.  The Person (and Orders) know nothing about the Grid.  You can write some code in the controller (or view) to bind the Orders to the Grid in some standard way.   If you take a look at the Telerik MVC Grid (which is free) you can see how they do it using lambdas/fluent API.  I understand you want some sort of pluggable Grid architecture here - but maybe then you need to require that all Grids implement a common API - if they are all displaying the same kind of data then that shouldn't be a difficult requirement.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with an interface that covers all three Grid types, and an abstract class that implements the interface and covers the things common to the first two?

Comment: What would I put in the interface if none of the properties are shared with the 3rd type? I would then be making the 3rd type explicitly implement them when they aren't needed.

Comment: Maybe the a enumeration property for the type of the grid, that way you will not have to use reflection to determine witch type it is.

Answer (score 1):

I would define an interface, which would be common to all 3 grid types.

```
public interface IGrid
{
    // define your Grid contract here
}
```

I would then create an abstract base class, which defined the things common to the first two types of Grid:

```
public abstract class GridBase : IGrid
{
}
```

And derive my two common grids from here:

```
public class GridTypeA : GridBase { }
public class GridTypeB : GridBase { }
```

Finally, my 3rd (but totally different Grid), comes from IGrid

```
public class ObtuseGridType : IGrid
{
}
```

Now, my person object just has an IGrid.

Comment: I guess I should have included that my grid contract does not need anything other than the properties

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you need to use reflection to get a type of the grid. If you write something like this, a *pseudocode*:

```
public abstract class BaseGrid {
   ... 
   ... 
   public abstract Type GetGridType();
}

public class Grid1 : BaseGrid {

   ...  
   ...
   public override Type GetGridType() {
      return typeof(Grid1 );
   }
}

public class Grid2 : BaseGrid {

   ...  
   ...
   public override Type GetGridType() {
      return typeof(Grid2 );
   }
}
```

You have a `GetGridType()` and don't need a relfection. The return value of that function can be any identifier you prefer based on your app design, not obviously Type.

Regards.

Comment: Is it really that expensive to use reflection in this case? I was told not to bother writing a GetType() method for something simple like getting a class name.

Comment: Is this not reflection anyway?  You're returning a Type object which is part of the reflection metadata.  That's all reflection is - querying the metadata.

Comment: @Gho5t: I wrote in the answer that the fact that my code GetGridType() return Type is just an example, you can choose any identifier you like. If you want to use a reflection for some design reasons that I don't know it'e prefectly fine. I mean there is no reason to use reflection ONLY for retrieving a type of the child class.

Comment: Yeah it is. I could use an enum...but really is it that important to avoid reflection at all costs?

Comment: @James: it's true, but questioner asks for useing reflection for acessing it after via properties I presume, by the way this is just a pseudocode, how I explain in the post. GetGridType can return whatever identifier he wants, to uniquely identify the Grid's type.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but think that you've got bigger problems here.  Suppose it's possible to have a Person object that can contain one of two entirely different objects.  All of your code will read like this:

```
if (grid is GridTypeA) {
    // do some stuff with type a
} else {
    // do some stuff with type b
}
```

That's precisely the kind of switching on types that object orientation is supposed to eliminate.  I'd look at the larger design and see if I could improve that.  For instance, why does a Person class contain a Grid pointer?  Speaking as a person - presumably what you're trying to model - I don't have a grid.

Comment: Hehe. No  you don't. It was actually just an example. It's a view model for a web page.

Answer (score 0):

My first question for you would be why the Person object needs to know about the grid - that sounds to me very much like you are allowing your domain level objects to take in external concerns - possibly ui for the grid or some sort of data storage concern.

Second question would be (as everyone else says) is there really any cause for abstraction with these three concepts of grid? Sounds like they are very different things.

That said, the two patterns I would look at if I were you would be [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) and [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Both these patterns will allow you to abstract away the concrete implementation details of the grids and their relation to the Person.